# Understanding Tierney Gibbs Sampler Kernel

Tags: bayesian, mathematical-statistics, simulation, markov-chain-montecarlo

In [subsection 2.2](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/%7Edas01/MyWeb/SCBI/Papers/Tierney94.pdf) Tierney (1994) states:

> Suppose $X \sim \pi$ and $f$ is a function on the state space $E$. Then the kernel
> $$
> P(x, A) = P(X\in A \mid f(X) = f(x))
> $$
> leaves $\pi$ invariant.

However doesn't seem to provide any intuition or proof as to why that's the case. I know that for the kernel to leave $\pi$ invariant we must have
$$
\pi = \pi P \qquad \qquad \pi(A) = \int P(x, A)\, d\pi(x) = \int Q(f(x), A) \, d \pi(x)
$$
How do we show this and what's the intuition behind this?

## Edit

Following comments here is my attempt. I will try to use the Law of Total Expectation. First, we can write
$$
\mathbb{E}_{\pi}[P(x, A)] = \mathbb{E}_\pi[P(X \in A \mid Y = y)]
$$
By the TOWER property we know that if $\nu$ is the distribution for $y$ then
$$
\mathbb{E}_\nu[\mathbb{E}_\pi[P(X \in A \mid Y=y)] = P(X\in A) = \pi(A)
$$
Now I only need to find what is the distribution $\nu$. Suppose $\pi$ is defined on $E$. Then $f(E)$ is image of the function $f$ and $y \in f(E)$. This means that our distribution $\nu$ must be defined on a sigma algebra of $f(E)$, for instance $\sigma(f(E))$
$$
\nu: \sigma(f(E))\to [0, 1]
$$
Since $E = f^{-1}(f(E))$ we can say $\nu$ is the pushforward of $\pi$ by $f^{-1} \circ f$
$$
\nu = (f^{-1} \circ f)_* \pi = \pi
$$
Therefore
$$
\int d\pi(x) \int P(X \in A\mid F(X) = f(x)) d\pi(x) = \pi(A)
$$
???

Comment: You indeed need to prove the last equality holds.

Comment: The intuition is that the move is according to $\pi$ restricted to one level set of $f$. Integrating over $x$ recovers all level sets,

Comment: @Xi'an Thanks! I gave it a go but I didn't quite manage to prove it, do you mind having a look?

Comment: The expression$$\mathbb E_π[P(x,A)]=\mathbb E_π[P(X∈A∣Y=y)]$$should write$$\mathbb E_π[P(X,A)]=\mathbb E_{fπ}[P(X∈A∣Y)]$$as there is only one random variable left to integrate.

Comment: Note that the kernel is not of practical interest for MCMC, since the entire sequence of simulations remains at the same level set $f(x)=f(x_0)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have a good idea of the kind of tools you could use to prove this statement, but I was a bit unclear about your attempted proof, in particular what you meant by the measure/distribution $\nu$.

Intuitively, you compute $P(X\in A) = \pi(A)$ in two steps: first integrate across each level set of the function $f$, then integrate over all level sets of $f$; this is equivalent to integrating over the whole space $E$. You can see this most clearly in the case where $f$ takes on only $1$ or $2$ values. You could try working through these cases in detail to develop more intuition.

For the general case, it helps to identify $P(X \in A \mid f(X)=f(x))$ as an integral over a level set of $f$.  In fact, $P(X \in A \mid f(X)=f(x))=\mathbb{E}[1_{X\in A}\mid Y=f(x)]=\varphi(f(x))$ where the function $\varphi$ is such that $\varphi (Y)=\mathbb{E}[1_{X\in A}\mid Y]$. (See e.g. Definition 8.24 in [Probability Theory](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781447153610) by Klenke for how this function is obtained. It's also discussed in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2483089/280385).)

By Theorem 4.10 (image measures) in the same book, or Lemma 6.12 in *Probability with Martingales* by Williams, we have that $ \int P(x, A)\, d\pi(x) =\int\varphi(f(x))\, d\pi(x)=\mathbb{E}[\varphi (f(X))]$. This is just $\mathbb{E}[\varphi(Y)]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[1_{X\in A}\mid Y]]$, which is equal to $\pi(A)$ by the law of total expectation.

Comment: I do not understand why someone downvoted this answer, which I find fine although I do not have access to the cited book. Maybe an explanation will come?

Comment: @Yves I've included additional references for anyone who doesn't have access to Klenke.